# What is the translation of "numerus qui est minor quam nullus"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I have difficulties on translating the sentence "numerus qui est minor quam nullus".
What's the English translation of this?

Comment: "Whichever number is less than nothing" I think is what it is.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you give some context for this sentence? The translation typically depends on it. You can edit your question to add details.

Comment: "Cum subrahitur numerus naturalis de alio naturali , exsultat interdum non naturalis sed numerus qui est minor quam nullus." That is on wikipedia and im practicing latin in that site lol.

Answer (score 3):

*Cum subrahitur numerus naturalis de alio naturali,*
When a natural number is subtracted from another natural (number),

*exsultat interdum non naturalis sed* ...
there sometimes results not a natural number but...

...*sed numerus qui est minor quam nullus.*
but a number which is less than zero.

The concept of [zero](https://yaleglobal.yale.edu/history-zero) reached Baghdad by 773 AD and appears in book Liber Abaci, or “Abacus book,”  by Fibonacci in 1202